# How to overcome mongoDB limitation on RAM

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It is my understanding that a given index/collection in mongoDB must be able to fit within the servers ram.

> Yes. MongoDB keeps most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.
>
> MongoDB does not cache the query results in order to return the cached results for identical queries.

([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/fundamentals/))

I have a collection that is well over 16gb big but only 16gb of ram on my server.  I view this server as sufficient for the modest needs of my project.  Two questions:

1. I don't have any good reason to split my database into multiple collections--further I imagine that querying multiple collections would be extremely slow (given that mongo wants to keep the collection live in ram).  Is there any other solution?
2. Is there any database with similar user interface to mongo that does not require that I keep my database in ram?

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement to fit your entire collection in RAM. For best performance, you want your indexes to fit in RAM (and the frequently accessed [working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-working-set) of documents), but even that's not a requirement.

See [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/) for more details on the topic.